# Load generation for a Docker registry

Tags: java, docker, jmeter, performance-testing, docker-registry

**How can one efficiently generate load to performance test a Docker registry?**

**I.e.:** Simulation of customer traffic to a registry endpoint where potentially all the images are different from one another.

- I was thinking of caching pre-built images from Docker hub and uploading them to my test Docker registry.
- Alternatively I was thinking of building images on the fly and uploading them to Docker - although this appears a little time inefficient and I would have to generate a tremendous number of Dockerfiles to ensure that the Docker images generates are different from one another.

Open to suggestions at the moment.

Comment: What kind of traffic that "customer traffic" is going to be? Mostly pulls? Pushes? Both equally?

Comment: Yes mostly just pulls and pushes. Around 4000 pulls and hour and 2000 pushes an hour. Total ingress/egress data totals around half a terabyte.